# html not rendered in ng-template

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-template

I have some json with correct format that passed from laravel controller and i want to show them recursively with angular but the HTML inside ng-template not rendered. what's wrong?

note: I replaced the angular default tag {{ }} with <% %>

```
<div id="treeViewContent" ng-init="getTreeData()">

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="directoryTree">
        <div class="tree-item" ng-click="loadDir(dir.address)">
          <i class="fa fa-folder orange"></i>
          <% dir.name %>
        </div>
        <ul ng-if="dir.subdir">
            <li ng-repeat="dir in dir.subdir" ng-include="'directoryTree'"></li>
        </ul>
      </script>
      <ul class="noselect">
          <li>
            <div class="tree-item" ng-click="loadDir('/')">
              <i class="fa fa-hdd-o blue"></i>
              {{ ucfirst(\Auth::user()->username) }}
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="dir in dirs" ng-include="'directoryTree'"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
```

and getTreeData() is:

```
  $scope.dirs = [];

  $scope.getTreeData = function()
  {
      $http.post("/admin/drive/treeData", {_token: csrf_code}).then(function(response)
      {
        if (response.status == 200)
        {
          $scope.dirs = response.data;
        }
        else
        {
          Flash({status: "failed", message: "Error"});
        }
      })
  }
```

and json data

```
 [  
   {  
      "name":"image",
      "address":"\/image",
      "subdir":[  
         {  
            "name":"document",
            "address":"\/image\/document",
            "subdir":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"document",
      "address":"\/document",
      "subdir":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"movies",
      "address":"\/movies",
      "subdir":[  

      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi @menhajrrt, a) looks like `getTreeData()` should the `dir` property in the local `$scope`. Can you provide the code of this function?
b) In the meantime, you could check in the developer console, whether the **directoryTree** tag's scope has any `dir` property.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg hi, a) post updated , b) it's json data is correct , this code has been worked in laravel 5.2 but in laravel 5.4 it has problem. i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the plunkr link `plnkr.co/edit/B33ZhzU03CyS45a0lX4w?p=preview`, the above code is working fine. Please check the json structure or post the json here.

Comment: Check plnkr link, it was similar json structure only.